# SQL Server : alternatives to INTERSECT

Tags: sql-server

I am writing an attempt at implementing a name search functionality via a SQL Server stored procedure.

Three tables are involved with the following definitions:

Employee table (other columns removed for brevity)

```
CREATE TABLE Payroll.Employee
(
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL  IDENTITY(1,1),
    EmployeeName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Employee PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EmployeeID),
);
```

Names table (single names stored with a a unique KeyNameID)

```
CREATE TABLE Payroll.KeyName
(
    KeyNameID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    KeyName NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
    RwVersion ROWVERSION NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT PK_KeyName PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (KeyNameID),
    CONSTRAINT UC_KeyName UNIQUE (KeyName)
);
```

EmployeeName (employee's name stored using the id for each single name)

```
CREATE TABLE Payroll.EmployeeName
(
    EmployeeNameID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    KeyNameID INT NOT NULL,
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_EmployeeName PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EmployeeNameID),
    CONSTRAINT UC_EmployeeName UNIQUE (KeyNameID,EmployeeID)
);
```

The `Employee` table has the following rows:

```
INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES (1, 'ayub kassim');
INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES (2, 'eric yuda');
INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES (3, 'james kassim');
```

Each of the above names are split and stored in the KeyName table as follows:

```
INSERT INTO KeyName (KeyNameID, KeyName) VALUES (1, 'ayub');
INSERT INTO KeyName (KeyNameID, KeyName) VALUES (2, 'eric');
INSERT INTO KeyName (KeyNameID, KeyName) VALUES (3, 'james');
INSERT INTO KeyName (KeyNameID, KeyName) VALUES (4, 'kassim');
INSERT INTO KeyName (KeyNameID, KeyName) VALUES (5, 'yuda');
```

The KeyNameIDs are then used to identify each employee's single name as follows (two records per employee):

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeName (EmployeeNameID, KeyNameID, EmployeeID) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO EmployeeName (EmployeeNameID, KeyNameID, EmployeeID) VALUES (2, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO EmployeeName (EmployeeNameID, KeyNameID, EmployeeID) VALUES (3, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO EmployeeName (EmployeeNameID, KeyNameID, EmployeeID) VALUES (4, 5, 2);
INSERT INTO EmployeeName (EmployeeNameID, KeyNameID, EmployeeID) VALUES (3, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO EmployeeName (EmployeeNameID, KeyNameID, EmployeeID) VALUES (3, 4, 3);
```

My search code is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspEmployeeSearch
    @SearchString1 NVARCHAR(20),
    @SearchString2 NVARCHAR(20)
AS
    DECLARE @StringLength INT = LEN(@SearchString2)

    SELECT @SearchString1 = RTRIM(@SearchString1) + '%'
    SELECT @SearchString2 = RTRIM(@SearchString2) + '%'

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF @StringLength = 0
        SELECT 
            EmployeeName,
            taxpin
        FROM 
            Employee 
        JOIN 
            EmployeeName ON Employee.EmployeeId = EmployeeName.EmployeeId 
        JOIN 
            KeyName ON KeyName.KeyNameId = EmployeeName.KeyNameId 
        WHERE 
            KeyName.KeyName LIKE @SearchString1;
    ELSE    
        SELECT 
            EmployeeName,
            taxpin
        FROM 
            Employee 
        JOIN 
            EmployeeName ON Employee.EmployeeId = EmployeeName.EmployeeId 
        JOIN 
            KeyName ON KeyName.KeyNameId = EmployeeName.KeyNameId 
        WHERE 
            KeyName.KeyName LIKE @SearchString1
        INTERSECT 
        SELECT 
            EmployeeName,
            taxpin
        FROM 
            Employee 
        JOIN 
            EmployeeName ON Employee.EmployeeId = EmployeeName.EmployeeId 
        JOIN 
            KeyName ON KeyName.KeyNameId = EmployeeName.KeyNameId 
        WHERE 
            KeyName.KeyName LIKE @SearchString2
```

The procedure expects two parameters. Where only one name is being searched, the second parameter would be a zero-length string.

So far it works with around 31% of the cost on SORT. The nested loops use 'index seek' which is good for me.

In short, if I am searching for **'ayub kassim'** I only want employee records with the full name **'ayub kassim'**. But if I search for **'kassim'** I want all employee records with **'kassim'** in the name.

My question is: Is it possible to implement this stored procedure using JOINS only, without the proprietary INTERSECT clause?

For the record I do not want to use LIKE because I need a very fast procedure and my employee table could run into hundreds of thousands of records.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "without the proprietary INTERSECT clause?" - what's proprietary about it? It's defined in the *foundation* part of the SQL Standard.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry I did not know that. Thanks.

Comment: Seems a bit odd to store the full name in one field in the employee table, if you store firstname, lastname and indexed these you could find your results without the need of the two other tables, using WHERE LastName = @SearchString1 AND FirstName = COALESCE(@SearchString2, FirstName)

Comment: @Steve Ford I though about that initially. The problem is, where I live many employees have up to four (4) names. I have not been able to find a better way to search in such a scenario.

Comment: I think IF @StringLength = 0 should be replaced with IF ISNULL(@StringLength, 0) = 0. I checked the stored proc and it is giving data in both cases. As far as an alternative to INTERSECT is concerned, we can use CTE for loading the data of the first portion of the else block's query and then use the CTE in JOIN to determine the final result in else block's query.

Comment: @RajanPatekar. Thank you I have learned something on the NULL issue. In regard to cte, I had considered that as well and it is an option. However, I just wanted to know if I can achieve the same results by using only joins.

Comment: @BensonO. You can try something like:  SELECT    *
FROM    Employee
INNER    JOIN EmployeeName ON Employee.EmployeeId = EmployeeName.EmployeeId
INNER    JOIN KeyName AS K1 ON K1.KeyNameId = EmployeeName.KeyNameId AND K1.KeyName LIKE 'ayub%'
LEFT    JOIN KeyName AS K2 ON K2.KeyNameId = EmployeeName.KeyNameId AND  K2.KeyName LIKE 'kassim%'

Comment: @RajanPatekar. This returns all records containing 'ayub'. Requirement: If I provide both parameters then only those records with both 'ayub' and 'kassim' in the name column should appear in the results.

Comment: This looks like it's actually a `relational division` problem - where you're wanting to find all employees who have all names in X (where X is currently separate parameters but should probably just be another table)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Actually, I do not know if it can be done any other way. As such I will still be content to be told it is not possible. I am learning the JOIN thing so that would be fine.

Comment: I was just trying to give you some search terms to find similar problems and solutions.

Comment: if a person can have upto 4 names then you could split the comparison by Surname and ForeNames, which would mean that the WHERE clause we change to WHERE Surname = @SearchString1 AND Forenames LIKE COALESCE(@SearchString2, '%')